# Onclick reload with other onclick function

Tags: javascript, onclick, reload

Is there someone who know if its posible to use 2 onclick in 1 button?
I hope to get reload page when i push the button.

Here is the orginal button:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="javascript:articleToCart('<z:esc mode="js" value=$z:value[article.number]>', document.getElementById('amount$z:iteration[article.current]').value)">
```

Best Regards
Frank

EDIT:

My version works, but i cant find the way to get the `return false` to work. This works in IE and Firefox.

`<center><input type="button" class="flowbutton" value="Kjøp" onclick="document.location.reload(true);javascript:articleToCart('<z:esc mode="js" value=$z:value[article.number]>',document.getElementById('amount$z:iteration[art‌​icle.current]').value)"> </center>`

Comment: why you require two onclick event when you can call two function on same onclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a function, which you already do, you can do as much in the javascript as you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function articleToCartMain() {
        articleToCart('<z:esc mode="js" value=$z:value[article.number]>', document.getElementById('amount$z:iteration[article.current]').value);
        //Put other function calls in here as well
        return false; //Prevents the page from reloading or scrolling to top
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return articleToCartMain();">Do something</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this type of inline JS event handlers (in the HTML source file), just use a comma between the two statements you want to put on the click event.

If you add a handler with JS, don't do `onclick = function() { //code of your second function };` because it'll overwrite previous handlers. in this case, addEventListener/attachEvent is the "clean" way to go.

Btw, about pseudoURLs (`javascript:`) :

- in href properties of your links it's usually considered bad practice. If this is a button, for god's sake, use a `<button>`... all A tags should have a real URL in href property.
- in the onclick ??? useless, erase it without fear.